# Easiest way to set up an IMAP mail server

Tags: email

I am new to setting up a mail server, and everywhere I look I get either outdated or really complex instructions on setting up a mail server.

Is there any simple methods on installing an IMAP mail server?

Comment: There is `mypostfixadmin`.  So long that you lock it down, it's pretty nice and fancy to have.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use Dovecot for mail server

1. Install the packages

   `sudo apt-get install dovecot-imapd dovecot-pop3d`
2. Configure the protocol you need to be used by appending the protocol in the file `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf`:

   `protocols = pop3 pop3s imap imaps`
3. Choose the mailbox you would like to use. Dovecot supports `maildir` and `mbox` formats. Edit the file `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf` and change the line

   `mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir # (for maildir)`

   or

   `mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/spool/mail/%u # (for mbox)`
4. Restart the service

   `sudo /etc/init.d/dovecot restart`
5. Use telnet to check that dovecot is working properly.

   `telnet localhost imap`

That's it.

PS. Also make sure your firewall is configured properly to accept connections on the appropriate ports.

Source : [Official Dovecot Server Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/dovecot-server.html)

Comment: Great answer. However, you might want to enhance this a little by explaining how to tell if one is using mbox or maildir formats, as well as the fact that on Ubuntu 14.04 Server, it uses Upstart for Dovecot now and so you have to do "start/stop/restart/status dovecot" type commands.

Comment: Also, I found that if you get a prompt for SSL, skipping it will cause dovecot not to load. You'll have to do a self-signed SSL on the mail until you can replace with a real cert. Also, `dpkg-reconfigure dovecot-imap` doesn't work -- you'll have to do `apt-get --purge remove dovecot-core dovecot-imapd dovecot-pop3d` to remove and start over.

Comment: Current dovecot version uses a /etc/dovecot/conf.d where it stores different configuration files, so protocol selection is made placing files there. Anyway, there's no need to modify anythin, default installation already sets everything right.

Comment: Docs can now be found at https://help.ubuntu.com/18.04/serverguide/dovecot-server.html, but I don't know if the rest of the answer needs reviewing since 2013...